# jquery .mousemove not working

Tags: animation, colors

I'm trying to get 3 squares with different colors to change when I move the mouse in the document. It's not working this way, so any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).mousemove(function () {
        var r1 = Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255);
        var g1 = Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255);
        var b1 = 180;
        var r2 = Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255);
        var g2 = Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255);
        var b2 = 100;
        var r3 = Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255);
        var g3 = Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255);
        var b3 = 20;
        $('.square1').css('background-color','rgb(' + r1 + ',' + g1 + ',' + b1 +')');
        $('.square2').css('background-color','rgb(' + r2 + ',' + g2 + ',' + b2 +')');
        $('.square3').css('background-color','rgb(' + r3 + ',' + g3 + ',' + b3 +')');
    });
});
```

Comment: Your `e` variable is nothing because it's not an argument to your handler.  Change to this: `$(document).mousemove(function (e) {`

Comment: thanks, I just corrected that. But still, it's not working. Is there any other problem with the code?

Comment: Solved it now. Thanks! I noticed the w and h variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing definitions for your w and h variables (unless you forgot to add it to the question). In my example below I set the w and h variables to the window width and height.

```
var $win = $(window),
    w = 0,h = 0,
    rgb = [],
    getWidth = function() {
        w = $win.width();
        h = $win.height();
    };

$win.resize(getWidth).mousemove(function(e) {

    rgb1 = [
        Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
        Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
        180
    ];
    rgb2 = [
        Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
        Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
        100
    ];
    rgb3 = [
        Math.round(e.pageX/w * 255),
        Math.round(e.pageY/h * 255),
        20
    ];

    $(".square1").css('background','rgb('+rgb1.join(',')+')');
    $(".square2").css('background','rgb('+rgb2.join(',')+')');
    $(".square3").css('background','rgb('+rgb3.join(',')+')');

}).resize();
```

I used arrays for the rgb values. Let me know if you need anything explained further.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/x0r6vznt/

Comment: Thanks, those undefined variables were exactly the problem. This solution seems nice. I ended up using alpha values too to get nicer colors. The result can be seen at the main page of http://tomasantunes.com